# prepareForSegue called twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

I have a `UINavigationController` that has a `UITableview` loaded in it. Inside this `UITableView` I have one `prototype` cell and I reused it a few times with static data that never changes and never will. So, I connected two push segues from the `viewControlller` it self to two their `destination` view controllers. This seemed to work just fine. To invoke these `segues`, I used `UItableViews` delegate method: `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` so I know which row was tapped and then, go to the correct `viewController`.

No, problem, it works.

I then added a third `viewController` and its accompanying, `segue` to match, same as the previous two and same setup in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` - now, when I tap the second cell, that was working, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called as expected, then it called the correct segue, then `prepareForSegue` is called. Then, `prepareForSegue` is called again (at this point, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` has not been called again) the `prepareForSegue` method then invokes the incorrect segue (The third segue I added).

I cannot figure out who is calling the `prepareForSegue` method for the second time and why its got the wrong identifier.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

**Some code samples**

Here is the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    switch (indexPath.row)
    {
    case CategoryFilter:
        {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"FilteredCategoryView" sender:self];
        break;
        }
    case PriceFilter:
        {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"FilterByPriceSegue" sender:self];
        }
    case ConditionFilter:
        {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SearchFilterConditionSegue" sender:self];

        }
    }
}
```

Then in the `prepareForSegue` method:

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"FilteredCategoryView"]){



       //No data to pass just yet 


    }
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"FilterByPriceSegue"]){
       //No data to pass just yet 

    }
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SearchFilterConditionSegue"]){

       //No data to pass just yet 
    }
}
```

In the above method - I am not passing data just yet, but I will. Its this method that gets called twice.

Comment: Added the only bit of code that calls segues menially. Not sure what other code you're looking for? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check properties on the segues if there are differences. Are all three segues connected to their own cell, or are any segues connected to the view/tableview? Sounds like a segue is being triggered automatically. Maybe the view has triggered segues that are not manual?

Comment: Each segue is connected tot he viewController. Clicking on each segue highlights the whole viewController and never the cell of the UitableView in the viewController. Removing code from didSelectRowAtIndexPath - no segues are invoked and no views are pushed, as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the `break` in the second and third case of your `switch` maybe it will help ;)

Change your switch with :

```
switch (indexPath.row)
{
    case CategoryFilter:
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"FilteredCategoryView" sender:self];
         break;
    }
    case PriceFilter:
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"FilterByPriceSegue" sender:self];
         break;
    }
    case ConditionFilter:
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SearchFilterConditionSegue" sender:self];
         break;
    }
}
```

If you don't put the `break` instruction in each of your cases the switch will do all the other case until the end of the switch or another `break` instruction.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I did forget the break. Normally something I don't forget. Such a simple thing. Thank you dude. Blonde moment!

Comment: enjoy ;) the obvious is sometimes the hardest to find ;)